# Does Ubuntu log when USB devices are connected?

Tags: usb, mount, log

When I connect a USB drive to an Ubuntu OS, would there be a text file which contains details of that connection and if so, where is that file located ? What is the name of that file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Does Ubuntu log when USB devices are connected?

**Yes**, Ubuntu *logs* when a USB device is connected. The file is `/var/log/syslog`. You can also view it by issuing the command `dmesg` (with optional `-c` argument to clear the log) or graphically using `Log file viewer`.

#### Is this file deleted upon shutdown?

**No**, This log does *not get wiped* upon shutdown. After a size limit is reached the logs are rotated, meaning new logs are continually written to `/var/log/syslog` while older records are pushed to compressed files named `/var/log/syslog.1.gz`, `syslog.2.gz`, ... in the same `/var/log` directory.

You can view the `/var/log` directory with rotated log files below:

[image]

Comment: Does this log get wiped upon system shutdown? Or is it down after a particular number of MBs?

Comment: I have edited the answer according to your question

Comment: If you want to see exactly what gets logged in realtime, you could `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, clear the screen, then connect the USB device.

Comment: `dmesg -c` will display and clear the dmesg log :(

Answer (score 11):

The area I look at is:

```
sudo cat /var/log/kern.log | grep usb
```

The output would look like the following:

```
May 25 07:38:51 mycomputer kernel: [  607.296847] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
May 25 07:38:54 mycomputer kernel: [  609.790892] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
May 25 07:38:54 mycomputer kernel: [  609.817462] usb 3-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
May 25 07:38:54 mycomputer kernel: [  609.817474] usb 3-2: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
May 25 07:38:54 mycomputer kernel: [  609.818399] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 13fe pid 3600: 4000
May 25 07:38:54 mycomputer kernel: [  609.818529] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
```

There are also compressed logs for kern.log You can search those with the following command:

```
sudo zcat /var/log/kern.log.2.gz | grep usb
```

The output would be in the same format as the the example above.

You can also search the syslog as follows:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep usb
```

This gives you results that look like this:

```
May 25 07:31:25 tardis-w520 kernel: [  161.469096] usb 1-1.5.5: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
May 25 07:31:25 tardis-w520 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.5"
May 25 07:31:25 tardis-w520 kernel: [  161.658587] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-1.5.5:1.0
May 25 07:31:25 tardis-w520 kernel: [  161.658685] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
May 25 07:31:25 tardis-w520 kernel: [  161.795563] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
May 25 07:38:51 tardis-w520 kernel: [  607.268280] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
May 25 07:38:51 tardis-w520 kernel: [  607.293280] usb 3-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
May 25 07:38:51 tardis-w520 kernel: [  607.293292] usb 3-1: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
```

To list the .gz log files you would:

```
sudo zcat /var/log/syslog.2.gz | grep usb
```

The resulting output would be in the same format as the previous.

If this is for forensics purposes there may be a better way.

Comment: The Kern.log does not get deleted after shutdown. Nor does the syslog. Both get compressed after a while.