# Wifi USB stick working but not displayed

Tags: 14.04, usb

I plugged a WiFi USB stick and I got instantaly access to Internet. Now I am curious to see the type of my uSB stick (USB 1.0, USB 2.0 or USB 3.0). But when I run ls `/media/begueradj/` I do not see it there. How to fix this?

EDIT:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:a103 Suyin Corp. Acer/HP Integrated Webcam [CN0314]
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Does this stick has some data storage capacity together with the ability to connect to the Internet? If it can do both, then update your question. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/666516/edit) your question and add the output of `lsusb` up there.

Comment: @user68186 no storage capacity

Comment: Only external storage devices show up as `/media/[username]/[flashdrivename]`. If there is no storage there is no folder called `[flashdrivename]`.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/186183/how-to-extract-a-list-of-all-devices-that-were-connected-to-my-pc-before about using `hwinfo` to get information about your USB.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices get both functions: Modem and USB storage.
But on Linux (Driver propietary problem) only recognize one function.
it's 'normal'.

Comment: so I can not see the speed of my USB port because it must be a storage capacity one?