# Ubuntu 12.10, suddenly HD performing ultra slow for no aparent reason

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive

On Ubuntu 12.10 AMD64. I have been using this computer with Ubuntu for a couple of years, and it has worked perfectly.

This HD is just one year old.

It is a 2TB HD. I have been using it mostly for a partition of 50GB for the Root folder, the /Home folder was just storing my backups and the profiles of the applications I have been using. So I coudl say I have not making use of this HD. I placed all my work files in an external HD, just for reasons like what has happened now.

Today I decided to check some files in another external HD, and finally decided to copy like 200GB of content from the external drive to the internal drive via USB 2.0, as this was taking 2 hours I decided to do other things and went away from the computer. Last time I checked there was like 45 minutes remaining, and went away again. Also I think the screen saver got activated, it has been a source of problems several times, with this and with other computers for the last years. It is set up so only the screen gets blank, never the HD. Many times I have not been able to wake up my computers.

The fact is that when I came back to my computer, it did not respond. Finally I had to do a hard reset. .... fast forwarding, now I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 again (for second time today) but the HD keeps being ultra slow.

What could I do? Is this a hardware problem? Is the HD damaged?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Does the file `/var/syslog` contain anything related to that drive when you attempt to access it?

Comment: Sorry, how do i do that? Please explain for a beginner. I have been usign Ubuntu for years, but only a an "office" user. I am not afraid of using the CLI, but please explain in more detail. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142050/does-ubuntu-log-when-usb-devices-are-connected/142057#142057)

Comment: Thanks, finally I bought a new HD. The older one (only 1 year old, fortunatelly the guarantee covers this) I spoiled. The new one of course runs smoothly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having some really weird HD performance issues in 12.10 in January or therabouts. If not for that, I'd say that the drive is probably on its way out.