# 1 of my 2 keyboards not working

Tags: keyboard, 19.10

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 (Dual booted with Windows) for my laptop. **Beside my laptop's keyboard, I'm using 2 more keyboards** (just call them keyboard A & keyboard B).

When I'm working, **my keyboard A is just randomly not working**, can't type or anything, **while laptop's keyboard are working fine and keyboard B has 50% chance that works well**.

If I plug it out and plug it in, it's working but it will be randomly die again.

The keyboard is working fine on Windows or another PCs, so **it's not the keyboard A's fault**.

I tried updating Ubuntu, using other versions of Ubuntu (such as 18.04, 19.04) but none of them works.

What should I do?

*Edit: I tried changing ports of both keyboard A and B but the same. Keyboard B works well but sometimes it doesn't, keyboard A is always the one die. 
Keyboard A and B are both mechanical keyboards, but keyboard A has detachable cable (usb-c to usb) when keyboard B doesn't.*

Comment: Can you confirm they are usb keyboards or wireless, and have you tried changing ports?  Does B keyboard work well if plug in to port keyboard A usually is?  Also the makes of keyboards might be useful.  A and B.

Comment: @crip659 Oh I forgot to add more details about it. Yes, I tried changing ports, Keyboard B work well but sometimes it doesn't. But keyboard A is always the one die.

Keyboard A and B are both mechanical keyboards, but keyboard A is using detachable cable when keyboard B isn't.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! So are your keyboards connected with USB? (You still haven’t confirmed this…) What does a detachable cable mean? (Could you include models of both keyboards and the computer?) Has your keyboard B started to fail after you wrote your original question (“keyboard B and laptop's keyboard are working fine” and later “Keyboard B works well but sometimes it doesn't”)?

Comment: @Melebius they're all conencted with USB, keyboard A has detachable cable USB-C to USB. I've checked many times again and it's just 50% chance that keyboard B works well and 50% chance it doesn't.

Comment: Said keyboards work well with Windows, confirm if dual booted on same computer or it is another computer.  This will decide if USB ports/cables are part of problem.  Did these keyboards come with windows drivers or are plug and play?

Comment: @crip659 Yes, dual booted on same computer, these keyboards are just plug and play.

Comment: Did a little googling and found this, can read it and see if it might help.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for help, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can check your logs (https://askubuntu.com/questions/142050/does-ubuntu-log-when-usb-devices-are-connected), or I think your best bet might be google ubuntu (make of) keyboards stop working.  Maybe also use linux, usb, randomly.  Mix and change words, good chance someone else has had this problem.